# Android TTS returns "Quota exceeded" for offline voices

Tags: android, google-text-to-speech

I have been using Google TextToSpeech for a long time in my apps, many of my users are using the offline voices so I had no problem with the number of resources using. But after receiving the latest update of GoogleTTS all of my users are getting the following error

```
03-13 14:42:29.298 29525-29571/? E/TTS.NetworkSynthesizer: ExecutionException during NetworkFetchTask
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: clx: RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: Quota exceeded for quota metric 's3-sessions' and limit 's3-session-limit' of service 'speechs3proto2-pa.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:...'.
```

Has google been adding new limitations to the offline tts, or is it some changes which has made my app use the online version of google tts? Anyway I would be more than thankful if anyone could guide me through this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I figured what the problem was, It had nothing to do with the latest update of android but mostly with the latest update of the US sanctions against Iran. If you are trying to use Google TTS from Iran you should know that you can no longer download the voices from Iran ip addresses.

The following approaches would solve the problem:

1. Guide the user to install a working proxy (Difficult but safer)
2. Use the governmental solutions like shecan.ir to bypass the sanctions (Easier but not so safe)